# API to download microsoft Team channel attachments

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

After searching in all the docs of Microsoft team finally came here to know whether any API exists to download channel message's attachment ,I'm not able to download file of channel message.
I had tried with this https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}  accordingly to groups api to download attachment but its not working.Any kind of help will appreciate.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried
Also, check if you need a key or something

Comment: @lzio -- Everything is fine from authorization side , i am passing all the required parameters but it looks like they are not providing any endpoints to download channel attachments

Comment: I think you better turn yourself on the Microsoft side. I can't help you much

Comment: @MohammadRaheem- Are you receiving the contentUrl? Please have a look [messages API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_get_message). Let us know what response you are getting and how you are trying to download it.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting contentUrl but it will not download file as it require login, with access token not able to download

Comment: Currently most of the MS Teams apis is in beta version, once stable version of apis released may be this issue automaticaly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Attachment's contentUrl is a reference to SharePoint document. You can use [driveitem/content](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content) API to download the content.